# Carbon setting timezone does not change timestamp value

Tags: laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I am trying to get the timestamp from a different timezone in Carbon / Laravel. Somethings change, but not the timestamp (whether I use `->format('U')` or `->timestamp`)

```
<?php

$datestring = '2021-05-29';
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datestring);

echo $date->format('H:i') . '<br>';
echo $date->timezone('Europe/London')->format('H:i') . '<br>';

echo $date->format('U') . '<br>';
echo $date->timezone('Europe/London')->format('U') . '<br>';

?>
```

Results:

```
00:00
01:00
1622246400
1622246400
```

Playground: https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/a62f40ea-38a8-4145-9851-5d061905cfa0

Answer (score 4):

Timestamp from other timezone than UTC does not exist.

Timestamp is by definition the number of second since `January 1st 1970 midnight UTC` "UTC" is actually explicitly in the definition, it aims to represent a universal point in time, that's why it's needed. If you have a number of second since an other date (such as Jan 1st 1970 GMT-5) it's not a timestamp, it's just a number of second from an arbitrary moment that belongs to your business logic, you can get it with:

```php
$date->diffInSeconds('1970-01-01 00:00:00 -05:00');
```

But be aware having to do this is the certain sign of a badly localized application.